# What do I need to do to upload ndk native symbolic links of a third party .aar?

Tags: android, android-ndk, build.gradle, native, crashlytics

I have a library which contains native .so files. This library has some java code and is used as an integration between the .so files and my app. This library is uploaded to an artifactory repository which is then used in the app as a gradle dependency.

The problem is that crashlytics ndk is enabled but the symbols for the libraries won't be uploaded because we don't have access to them.

Originally the integration library with the native code was part of the same project as a module. This meant that we could tell crashlytics where to find the .so files so it can upload the symbols.

This is the original configuration which now not only has the issue of not uploading the symbols but it also crashes the build.

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk = true
    androidNdkLibsOut 'native/libs'
    androidNdkOut 'native/obj'
    manifestPath 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

The crash can be fixed by removing some lines, but it doesn't help with uploading the symbols.

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk = true
    manifestPath 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

**Edit 1**

I've found this on crashlytics site: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#uploading-symbols-for-external-dependencies

, but I am not sure how it would work.

Comment: Hey, Fabric/Firebaser here - could you add the error that you get when that original configuration crashes?

Comment: @KevinKokomani The original crash or issue, was caused by the fact that we moved the ndk files and .so files out of the main app and placed them into an external dependency.

The problem that remains is how can we upload the symbols from that external dependency using the the ApiKey of the main app.

Comment: If the library is an external project, how exactly are you including it as a dependency? And does this library project have a gradle file with an externalNativeBuild block, or does your app's build.gradle have something setup like that?

Comment: It is included as a gradle dependency. It downloads an aar which contains the .so files and some wrapper classes. We do control the library, what I was thinking was to upload the .so files to the artifactory repository and download them just for the task of uploading the symbolic links. Writing this I realize I could just unpack the .aar file.

Comment: Unpacking the .aar makes sense, you should be able to get the .so's that we need from there, but they'll probably be stripped. You'll probably end up with some symbolication but not the best symbolication possible if that's the case. The binaries should be already be organized the way they are supposed to be in a lib directory inside the .aar, so you should be able to extract the lib directory somewhere and run the symbol generator on that directory. It's possible that the gradle build process (StripDebugSymbols) will somehow modify it and you'll have to point it to that outputted path.